# how to construct unit test for controller with $state?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

Trying to write a unit test for my controller:

```
 app.controller('StartGameCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout,$state) {
      $scope.startGame = function () {
        $scope.snap = false;
        $scope.dealCards();
        debugger;
        $state.go('cpu');
      }
    });
```

I wrote this jasmine unit test:

```
describe('snap tests', function() {
  beforeEach(module('snapApp'));
  var scope, createController, state;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller,$state) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function () {
      return $controller('StartGameCtrl', {
        '$scope':scope,
        '$state':state
      });
    };
  }));


  it('startGame should call dealcards', function () {
    var controller = createController();
    spyOn(scope, 'dealCards');
    scope.startGame();
    //expect(scope.dealCards).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

when I run my karma test I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$state.go')
at startgamectrl.js:9
```

Comment: does your `snapApp` module included `ui.router` module in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've assigned the `$state` local to be `state` (an undefined var in your spec) instead of the injected `$state` service.

Rather than do that though, I'd just create a spy for `$state`. For example...

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    state = jasmine.createSpyObj('$state', ['go']);
    createController = function () {
        return $controller('StartGameCtrl', {
            '$scope':scope,
            '$state':state
        });
    };
}));
```

Then you can test that it's called

```
expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cpu');
```